# UITableView not scrolling inside of UIScrollView

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, ios8, xcode6

in my view controller I have a ScrollView for content adaptation on various devices .. I need to insert a tableView inside the ScrollView but I noticed that my tableView not scrolling when it is inside a ScrollView. Can someone help me figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your table view to scroll set the content size of scroll view less than that of your table view.

Comment: you can not do this because the view controller where is the tableView is not the same view controller that contains the ScrollView .. I'm calling various view controllers with addChildViewController

Comment: you can still get the frame through property